# How can I speed up an ASC sort on a column that only holds an integer between 0 and 9 across multiple millions of rows?

Tags: postgresql, order-by

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id  TEXT    NOT NULL,
  bar INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX foo_bar_idx ON foo(bar) WHERE NOT bar = 0;
```

I can sort on the `bar` column in DESC order about 3 times faster than I can sort on the `bar` column in ASC order. I assume an index on the column isn't helping with the sort since, relatively speaking w/ millions of rows, most of the values are the same.

The default value for the `bar` column is 0, but I only care about rows that have a value between 1 and 9, so my query includes a where clause for that. Not sure if the partial index is helping.

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE bar > 0 ORDER BY bar DESC;
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE bar > 0 ORDER BY bar ASC;
```

Across 9M rows, explain analize shows the ORDER BY DESC taking less than a second, and ORDER BY ASC taking a little over 3 seconds. Approximately 117K of the 9M rows get filtered by the WHERE clause.

Is the ORDER BY DESC faster because it doesn't necessarily have to worry about the 0 values? Any way to speed up the ORDER BY ASC query? Or... should I just be happy w/ a 3 second query time for a table w/ 9M rows in it? I'm continually adding rows, so I'm worried about the query time increasing over time...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the same syntax for all of your `WHERE` clauses (your index would build for negative values of `bar`, but you never `SELECT` those)

`CREATE INDEX` has an implicit order of `ASC`, so it unlikely that not specifying the indexing order alone is the source of your problem (as you stated the `DESC` sort is faster).

Naively, I'd also recommend that you include the `id` column in your index, but this may negatively affect insert/index rebuild performance, as well as overall disk and memory usage.

```
CREATE INDEX foo_bar_idx
  ON foo(bar ASC, id ASC) 
  WHERE bar > 0
```

You could try converting all zeros to `NULL` (and setting `NULL` as the default), then changing your `WHERE` clauses to `WHERE bar IS NOT NULL`. So your create table code would look like

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id TEXT NOT NULL,
  bar INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Once you have `NULL`s established, you could alternatively play around with the `NULLS FIRST` / `LAST` parameters in your index, rather than using a `WHERE` clause, but that is unlikely to improve performance.